# Can you create a tag for”Drawn Together”, “Ugly Americans”?

Tags: support

can you please create tags for: Drawn Together Ugly Americans and Atlantis Milo’s return? And add also other new tags? It will be helpful if you would do this.

Answer (score 3):

We can do so, if there is a question about those shows/movies.

Until then there's no need.

If you have a question about a show that does not have a tag...ask it and add a comment requesting the tag...at least that's probably the optimal method.

Alternatively, if these questions already exist...link them in your question above and someone can take care of it.

Comment: You never know who will need it, maybe someone in future might need it.

Comment: Because, some of these tags I have few questions to ask and that’s why.

Comment: Then it can be created **when it's actually needed**.. We don't create tags *just in case*.

Comment: As I said, if you have a question...ask it. We can add the tag later.

Comment: Of course, I do have. Some of them are about when will come back or will be new seasons? Because maybe someone else knows well when it is.

Comment: Those sorts of questions are not acceptable on Movies and TV/. I suggest you reread the [help] guide

Comment: Asking about "A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series." is **specifically** off-topic.

Comment: Where I can ask to make another site for Stack Exchange? Like site called tv series and to be allowed to make discussions about when will be released or when will come back with new seasons

Comment: I very much doubt if there is a site on the Stack Exchange network where rumours would be acceptable. This is not a *discussion*-based site.

Comment: But if you must try - http://area51.stackexchange.com/